# Zookeeper Release Files - whats the difference

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I've looked everywhere and I'm new at this open source stuff but... what's the difference between:[   ]

- apache-zookeeper-3.5.6-bin.tar.gz 2019-10-16 01:35  8.8M
- apache-zookeeper-3.5.6.tar.gz     2019-10-16 01:35  3.0M

I'm guessing since the top is bigger it's shipping with more dependencies? I having issues running apache-zookeeper-3.5.6.tar.gz has classes missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
apache-zookeeper-X.Y.Z.tar.gz is standard source-only release
apache-zookeeper-X.Y.Z-bin.tar.gz is the convenience tarball which contains the binaries
```

https://zookeeper.apache.org/releases.html